# How can I store multiple values passed in the select option in the javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am passing two values in a select option like this.

```
<option value="<%=jo22.getInt("amount")%>&<%=jo11.getString("id")%>"><%=jo22.getString("name")%><br><%=jo22.getString("currency")%>&nbsp;&nbsp; <%=jo22.getInt("amount") %> per unit</option>

<%} %></select>

<input type="text" id="demo1" value="">


    <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
      document.getElementById("demo1").value = x;
function getID() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
      document.getElementById("demo1").value = x;
}
</script>
```

Now I have applied a script function of select on change to get one value of the select option. I mean I want to get the amount and not the plan id of the select option into variable x of javascript function. How to get it? Please help.

Comment: store all data in data attributre separetly so u can retrive it and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I used substring function of string simply to get the value of amount before '&' character.

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
 var str = x;
  var res = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('&'));
  document.getElementById("demo1").value = res;
```

function getID() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;

```
  var str = x;
  var res = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('&'));
  document.getElementById("demo1").value = res;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**set And get multiple value in option with JSON Object**

```js
function showData() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  var obj = JSON.parse(x);
  var amount=obj.amount;
  var id=obj.id;
  alert("amount = " +amount +"id = "+id);
 
}
```

```html
<select onclick="showData();" id="mySelect">
 <option value='{"amount":"4444", "id":"11"}'>4444 11</option>
</select>
```